# openxml - word - copy bookmark content to a new document

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word, openxml-sdk

I am trying to copy a bookmark from word document 1 (in the bookmark, I can have text, table, charts with specific formating) and paste it in a bookmark in word document 2.

It was so simple to do it with VBA

```
Sub MyBookmark()
 Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="ToBeSaved2"
 Selection.Copy

Dim oDoc As Word.Document
Set oDoc = Documents.Add(Template:="C:\Temp\Template.docx", NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0)
oDoc.Activate
 
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="ToBeSaved2"
Selection.Paste

oDoc.SaveAs2 ("C:\Temp\NewVersion.docx")
oDoc.Close
 End Sub
```

But with c# and openxml, I cannot find anything on that.
At my stage, I am able to find the bookmark content, but I loose formatting, and charts.

Thank you

Comment: As the methods will be identical you are not doing the exact same calls with the exact same parameters in C#. That is simple.

Comment: Really ? Just to find a bookmark, you need 20 coding lines, and that's just for the text (without format...)

Comment: So this is COM. Language is irrelevant. You are accessing the Word object model. Therefore **any** programming languages will call the same COM functions (normally exposed as methods/properties) with the same parameters to get the exact same result. **You are not doing that**.

Comment: **POST YOUR CODE**. Your VBA is recorded, naughty.